# How to get value from dictionary by key and compare that value with zero c#?

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I have dictionary, and I want to threw exception, if value(not key) is < 0.
But i am don't know how to check this condition. 
Help me please

```
public Dictionary<string, double> Components = new Dictionary<string, double>();

if (/*Components key amount < 0*/)
 {
   throw new Exception("Value can't be smaller then 0!");
 }
```

Comment: You're only trying to check for bad values when you need to retrieve them?

Comment: You are not asking about "how to get value from dictionary by key and compare that value with zero like `Components["Amount"]< 0` " ? Please [edit] post and clarify what you expect to happen showing input data and desired output. Feel free to remove unrelated code for `Error` and `switch` at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the value for a given key and check what the value is:

```
double value;
if (Components.TryGetValue(key, out value) && value < 0)
{
    throw new Exception("Value can't be smaller then 0!");
}
```